# After update my Donation page goes to a random php location with no donation links

Tags: contributions

I tried creating a new form and get a link that goes to this page as do all my preexisting ones.

[image: the lost page ot goes to.]

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! It would be useful if you could provide some more detail so that people can provide better help. Which CMS and version are you using? (WordPress, Drupal, Joomla) Which version of CiviCRM did you upgrade from and to?